# Toggle a footer by clicking a button situation

Tags: jquery, css, slidetoggle

I have been working on this for a week or so and I have a solution that works but not very well.

I have a hidden footer with a tab like button above it. When this button is clicked my footer will then slide up and push that button up as well.

**My problem** comes from me being unable to place my button inside of the footer. Since the footer is hidden until clicked the button would also be hidden.

One method I tried was instead of hiding the footer I placed a negative `bottom` on it to hide it until clicked. This was working well but once it was clicked you could just scroll back down and it was never hidden after that.

I then decided I would have to hide/show it but this is where the problem came about with the button. Since the footer is hidden I can not place the button inside of the footer. Since the button is outside of he footer I have tried to animate it but it would not animate at the same time which was very odd.

The final solution I did was using css3 easing but it still is not perfect or even usable due to how un-flushed it is.

***I am trying to make both animate at the exact time while looking as if they are one object.***

**Here is my `HTML`**

```
<span class="fTab">Open Footer</span>
<footer>
</footer>
```

**Here is my `CSS`**

```
footer {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.69);
}

.fTab {
  width: 15%;
  height: 4em;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 2em;
  display: block;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.69);
  color: #c1c1c1;
  line-height: 4em;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.fTab.current {
  bottom: 20%;
}
```

**Here is my `jQuery`**

```
function footer() {
  var footerH = $('footer');
  var fH = footerH.height();

  $('.fTab').on('click', function() {
      $(this).toggleClass('current');
      $('footer').slideToggle(500);
  });
}

footer();
```

Here is the [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/LC2Tr/1/) and here is another option I was trying, [JSFIDDLE 2](http://jsfiddle.net/LC2Tr/3/)

Here is the [LIVE SITE](http://jpowell43.mydevryportfolio.com/temp/) if that is needed.

If you need anything else then let me know and I appreciate any and all help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've built a bare bones fiddle for you, with just the effect: http://jsfiddle.net/wa989/

The trick is transitioning both the `bottom` value of your button and the `height` of the footer. No need to slide with jQuery, since you can use CSS3 transitions for both the button's position and the footer's height.

You may want to use jQuery to switch the button's text to 'Hide footer' though.

Comment: Thank you so much! This is an interesting set up and I greatly appreciate the help you have offered.

Comment: How can I find out programatically whether the menu is collapsed or not. I tried $(this).is(":active"), but it does not seem to work as I expected.

Comment: Loved this one. Customizing it right now, to work how I need it to work in my new site design. You rock, Severin.