# Slideout Footer on button click Javascript

Tags: javascript

I followed the steps in this tutorial to make a slideout footer. http://tutorialzine.com/2013/08/slideout-footer-css/

I am trying to make this footer reveal itself with a button click instead of scroll.  Something similar to what was discussed here on this question [Toggle a footer by clicking a button situation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19842353/toggle-a-footer-by-clicking-a-button-situation)  except
I don't want footer to slideout into view, but the whole page to slide up to reveal the footer behind. Effect similar to the Gnome-Shell-3 Message Bar.

I tried used a scroll to method to trigger page scrolling up but i am unable to disable the actual scroll. Any Idea how to achieve this?

Comment: Where are the code you have tried

Comment: Yes, jQuery is an option. I am using Zepto library which is almost drop-in replacement for jquery code.  I will upload the code in jsfiddle and let you know. I just added an empty div at the bottom of the page with anchor tag. and triggered a scroll to that tag on the button click.